# Can other users see environment variables set by root?

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

If I'm logged in as root and did `export MY_VAR=foo`, can I then ssh in as `jason` and `echo $MY_VAR` and get `foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exported environment variables are in the environment of the shell, and of child processes started after you exported them. The SSH shell you started later is unlikely to be a child process of your existing root shell. So, `echo $MY_VAR` won't get you `foo` because you did `export MY_VAR=foo` in a different shell.

However, users can read the *initial* environment variables of their own processes (root can do so for any user), since these are available in `/proc/<PID>/environ`. Variables exported after the shell started won't show up in that file, however.

Comment: Thanks. So just to clarify if I `export MY_VAR=foo` and then start a process using `service MY_SERVICE start`. `MY_SERVICE ` will indeed be able to read `MY_VAR`? Assuming i remain in a session as root.

Comment: @JasonJoslin for that specific case, the `service` script sanitizes the environment, so your service won't be able to read `MY_VAR`.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer and comments. I found that the service i wanted to start required me to set the `env` in a config script that is loaded when the system starts up. thanks again